# Restore IinfluxDB database from TSM files after accidental DROP DATABASE

Tags: restore, influxdb, data-loss

I am trying to rescue data from accidentally dropped InfluxDB database. I restored .tsm files using `foreman` data recovery tool. Now comes the hard part: restoring database from only tsm files. I tried to use `influx_inspect export` according to this github [issue](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/8688), but I am not sure about paths - I got errors like `panic: lstat /home/dipi/.influxdb/data: no such file or directory` - okay, created that directory, and `export: invalid directory structure for Desktop/rescued/tsm/31095504.tsm` - no idea what's wrong.